# Are fenugreek, mushroom herb the same thing?

Tags: seeds, herbs

I just bought a pack of fenugreek seeds. The seller site labels them as "mushroom herb" and "fenugreek", but they came in a packet with Cyrillic letters and a sticker with English instruction to grow "mushroom herb." "Fenugreek" is not printed anywhere on the packet. The seeds do look similar to [a picture I found on Wikipedia of fenugreek seeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenugreek).

Having checked online, it seems mushroom herb (rungia klossii?) and fenugreek (kasoori methi in Hindi?) are said to have different origins and the two names rarely appear in one article. It seems strange that there isn't any discussion that they are the same plant if they really are. Also curious is the fact that I can't find much information on the former.

Answer (score 1):

Fenugreek's botanical name is *Trigonella foenum graecum'*; it's an annual plant and is in a different plant family (Fabaceae) from *Rungia klossii*, which is an evergreen perennial in tropical regions, so it would seem these are two different plants. More information on *Rungia klossii* here https://www.jekkas.com/products/mushroom-plant, but without a botanical name for what you've been supplied, there's no real way of knowing what you've got.